# SQL: Cross join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

```
SELECT * FROM training.dbo.[PERSON] P
LEFT JOIN training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY PC ON (P.PERSON_ID=PC.PERSON_ID)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PC2.POSITION training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY) PC2 
WHERE PC.POSITION IS NULL
```

the cross join part is not working giving the error 
"Incorrect syntax near '.'."

I can't fix it, and been fixing it for about an hour. Please tell me my error

Comment: There's no FROM in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `FROM` in the `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM training.dbo.[PERSON] P
LEFT JOIN training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY PC ON (P.PERSON_ID=PC.PERSON_ID)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PC2.POSITION FROM training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY) PC2 
WHERE PC.POSITION IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the FROM keyword from the sub query. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    training.dbo.[PERSON] P
    LEFT JOIN training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY PC 
        ON (P.PERSON_ID=PC.PERSON_ID)
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            PC2.POSITION 
        FROM
            training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY) PC2 
WHERE 
    PC.POSITION IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the positions that people do *not* have, then this is the query that you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM training.dbo.[PERSON] P CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT PC2.POSITION FROM training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY
     ) pp LEFT JOIN
     training.dbo.PERSON_CAREER_HISTORY PCH
     ON P.PERSON_ID = PC.PERSON_ID AND pp.POSITION = PC.POSITION
WHERE PC.POSITION IS NULL;
```

The `join`s are not correct in your version (as well as the problem with the subquery).  Otherwise, I cannot figure out the purpose of your original query.